# spread syntax Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, ecmascript-5, transpiler, spread-syntax

I can't figure out how to port this code properly so that it's compatible with Internet Explorer...

```
const merged = [].concat(...responses.map(res => res.data));
```

How do I simply replace the spread syntax?

Comment: Found it!

const merged = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], responses.map(function (res) {return res.data} ));

Comment: @ Vincent, From your last comment. I can see that you had solved the issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and mark it as an answer may help other community member in future who have same kind of question.

Comment: The [`...` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is _not_ an operator

Answer (score 2):

const merged = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], responses.map(function (res) {return res.data} ));